# Azure CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists() throws Forbidden (403) on Local Development

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I've started getting 403 Error on blobContainer.createIfNotExists. Following is the source code.

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        string blobContainerName =string.IsNullOrEmpty(_sessionContext.DomainName) ? "localdevblob": _sessionContext.DomainName.ToLower();
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Things verified:

- container name is lower case & confirms to the standard
- the local blob storage is accessible in the Storage Explorer and works fine in reading / uploading content
- connection string is:
  *add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true"*

Anticipating that upgrading the library might fix the issue:

- Upgraded the Storage Emulator to 5.2
- Upgraded the Nuget package WindowsAzure.Storage to 8.4.0 (it was 8.1.0 earlier but that was already giving error)

The exception screenshot is below:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Apparently, i just downloaded the sample from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-dotnet-getting-started.git and that works too. and when i compared the cloudBlobClient object in my project and the sample project i found that for some strange reason I found that blobClient (in my project) is missing "AuthenticationHandler" and the "Key" which would be causing the issue. But these 2 values are present in the sample project.

[image]

Comment: Can you share 2 things: 1) What's the timezone you're working in and 2) value of `storageAccount` variable?

Comment: 1) UK timezone   2) devstoreaccount1 (uri: http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1)

Comment: Regarding #1, it is GMT+1, right? Or is it GMT?

Comment: Yes, it is GMT+1 (during the daylight savings).

Comment: Hmmm...That's weird. I just tried creating a blob container and it worked fine for me (I used the same library & emulator version as you have). What's the name of the blob container you're trying to create?

Comment: Apparently, i just downloaded the sample from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-dotnet-getting-started.git and that works too. and when i compared the cloudBlobClient object in my project and the sample project i found that for some strange reason I found that blobClient (in my project) is missing "AuthenticationHandler" and the "Key" which would be causing the issue. But these 2 values are present in the sample project. Added the screenshot above in main message. Any ideas ?

Comment: As Gaurav Mantri said, I can create blob container using Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library and Azure storage emulator on my side too. You said the GitHub sample works on your computer, I find the GitHub sample using  WindowsAzure.Storage v7.0.0, please try to downgrade WindowsAzure.Storage to v7.0.0 for your project and check if your code works.

Comment: Besides, some community members report that [ApplicationInsights might cause the 403 error when access storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662526/azure-storage-emulator-403-forbidden), you can check it.

Comment: It was working in another project of mine, so i picked up the web.config from the other project and replaced in the current one and voila it worked. Apparently, ApplicationInsights is definitely one of the culprit for introducing this issue but there seems to be more and I need to compare & try out all other changes to confirm what all other config entries are causing the issue and what resolved the issue. @FredHan - can i request you to post that AI issue as an answer ? so that i can flag that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> getting 403 Error on blobContainer.createIfNotExists

I created a sample to reproduce the issue on my side, the code works fine with installing `WindowsAzure.Storage sdk` **v8.1.0** to **v8.1.4** and **v8.4.0**.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

container.CreateIfNotExists();
```

And I also test the code with WindowsAzure.Storage v7.0.0, it works too.

Besides, some community members report that the WindowsAzure.Storage sdk returns 403 error when do storage operations if **ApplicationInsights** is installed in project, this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662526/azure-storage-emulator-403-forbidden) discussed it.

Comment: The main issues seems to have been caused by ApplicationInsights, removing that resolved the issue.

Comment: Here also ApplicationInsights caused the problem after Upgrading Azure Storage Emulator to 5.10. Resolved it by updating ApplicationInsights from 2.4.0 to 2.10.0 (todays latest version).